# Get value from EditText

Tags: kotlin, android-edittext

I want to log in from firebase.
But I can't get the value from EditText.

**MyCode**

```
var name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.signName)
var email = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.signEmail)
var password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.signPass)
val mEmail = email.text.toString()
val mPass = password.text.toString()

Log.d("eee", "data $mEmail $mPass")

btnOK.setOnClickListener {
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mEmail, mPass)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("sign", "create:success")
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainLoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Log.w("sign", "create:failure", task.exception)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                name.setText("")
                email.setText("")
                password.setText("")
                name.requestFocus()
            }
        }
}
```

Nothing appeared in the log.

Log is : 2020-05-17 *** D/eee: data

Error is : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null

Comment: You're collecting data as soon as views are created.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing these two lines inside the onClickListener.

```
mEmail = email.text.toString()
mPass = password.text.toString()
```

Comment: Thank you.
I'm embarrassed, as if I asked you something too simple.(^///^)